# Clarity Datagrid dynamic data row coun5 based on available space?

Tags: datagrid, vmware-clarity

Does the Datagrid support the notion of varying the number of data rows according to the available vertical space?

Hence, as the browser changes size the table header and footer areas remain fixed in size and the data area space varies to show whatever number of rows that will fit in the available vertical space.

This is to avoid a situation where scrolling is required.

Answer (score 0):

Clarity does not have this feature, but you could manually set the height of the Datagrid in the application based on the number of rows you have displayed. The goal currently is to minimize vertical jumpiness, so we keep the same height.